# Multicore usage in Spark and Scala and memory sharing

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm new to Spark, Scala and I have a few questions -

1. When I set `master` to `local[2]`, does it mean that, whenever I perform something like `rdd.map( ... ).collect()`, the `map` function will execute on 2 cores?
2. Following up on 1, will it be optimal if the number of items in RDD is equal to the number of cores? (so that each map is done in one core.)
3. How is memory shared if I reuse values?

   i.e.

   ```
   val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local["+cores+"]")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   // in practice the following will be sparse matrix which I want shared between threads
   val myHugeValue = 100

   // in practice the following would interact with myHugeValue
   sc.parallelize(Array.range(0, cores)).map(myHugeValue + _).collect()
   ```

   In the above, will the `myHugeValue` be copied to each mapper function as it uses `myHugeValue`? If so, how do I change the impl so that it doesn't get copied over?

Edit 1:

To be more specific for 2.,
Suppose there are 10 nodes or worker cores in my cluster, then won't the processing be done most efficiently if my data is split into 10 parts such that each node can process its batch? Is there a reason to split data into smaller chunks and increase network overhead?

As far as the reason I do not want to copy the value `myHugeValue` is because its a HUGE object and would take time copying for EVERY map operation. The map operations are called for a lot of iterations. I would rather want to *cache* the object once per cluster and then call map function repeatedly. Is there a Spark way of doing this?